# About the definition/motivation/properties of the twisted chiral superfield in ${\cal N}=2$ theories in $1+1$ dimensions

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, research-level, supersymmetry

The following is in the context of the ${\cal N}=2$ supersymmetry in $1+1$ dimensions - which is probably generically constructed as a reduction from the ${\cal N}=1$ case in $3+1$ dimensions.

- In the $\pm$ notation what is the definition of ${\cal D}_+$ and ${\cal D}_{-}$, which I understand from context to be the gauge covariant superderivatives. (..It would be great if someone can relate them to the usual definition in the notation of say Wess and Bagger..)
- So what is the meaning/motivation of defining a twisted chiral superfield as, 
  $\Sigma = \{\bar{{\cal D}}_{+}, {\cal D}_{-}\}  $ (..naively this looks like an operator and not a field - I guess there is some way of arguing that the derivative terms which are not evaluated on something actually go to zero..)

I am guessing that in the above context it will be helpful if someone can explain as to what is meant by the following decomposition/reduction of the gauge field from $3+1$ dimensions,

$\sum _ {\mu = 0}^3 A_\mu dx^\mu = \sum _{\mu =0} ^1 A_\mu dy^\mu + \sigma (dy^2-idy^3) + \bar{\sigma}(dy^2+idy^3)$ ?

- From the above (does it/how does it) follow that one can write $\Sigma$ as,

$\Sigma = \sigma + \theta\lambda + \theta \bar{\theta}(F+iD)$

(..where I am not sure if $F,D,\sigma$ are real or complex scalar fields...and $\lambda$ is a Weyl fermion..)

- What is the R-charge of this twisted chiral super field? 
  (..from some consistency conditions I would think that its 2..but I am not sure..)

I guess that the R-symmetry transformations act as,

- The "right" R symmetry keeps $\theta^-$s invariant and maps, $\theta^+ \mapsto e^{i\alpha}\theta^+$, $\bar{\theta}^+ \mapsto e^{-i\alpha}\bar{\theta}^+$
- The "left" R-symmetry keeps $\theta^+$ invariant and maps, $\theta^- \mapsto e^{-i\alpha}\theta^-$, $\bar{\theta}^- \mapsto e^{i\alpha}\bar{\theta}^+$.

Though I am not sure and like to understand as to why one wants to think of these two different R-symmetry groups as having two different origins - one coming from the rotation symmetry of the two spatial dimensions of the original $\cal{N}=1$, $1+3$ theory and another coming from R-symmetry of the $\cal{N}=1$, $U(1)$ gauge theory.

Answer (score 1):

After dimensional reduction from 4 to 2 dimensions, it is convenient to simply label the last two remaining dimensions as $+$ and $-$ instead of 1 and 2. So, basically you have ${\cal D}_- = {\cal D}_1$ and ${\cal D}_+ = {\cal D}_2$.

As for a motivation for twisted chiral superfields, I'm going to quote Witten [[http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9301042]](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9301042):

> Sigma models containing both chiral and twisted chiral superﬁelds are quite lovely. Since mirror symmetry turns chiral multiplets into twisted chiral multiplets, it is likely that
>   consideration of appropriate models containing multiplets of both types is helpful
>   for understanding mirror symmetry.

The introduction given by Witten on twisted chiral superfields in the above paper should cover most of your questions.

I am curious though, where did you find your equations? I'm a bit confused by the F-Term in your twisted chiral superfield, as I thought it was common practice to use the WZ-gauge for these types of fields?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My notation is that from this lecture of Witten, http://www.math.ias.edu/QFT/spring/witten13.ps. Look at the bottom of page 11 and top of page 12.

Comment: Can you kindly help about the last part of my question about the existence of two "different" R-symmetries. For example isn't there a mismatch between what these two R-transformations do as written in say Page 14 of the paper you have linked to and say, what is there on Page 59 of these notes, http://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/0504147v1.pdf. May be if you can make explicit the R-symmetry transformation that is being alluded to in the first paragraph of the "Symmetries" section of the paper that you linked to.